# FFMPEG Audio, video out of sync

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm creating Video using FFMPEG from pngs. The problem is on creating the video, and combining with video, its never in sync.

Create video:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/ubuntu/pngs/* -vcodec libvpx -r 25 -b 1024k -y video.avi
```

generate audio

```
ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -i wav_file.wav -acodec libvorbis video.avi
```

these snapshots were taken at 25fps from a video. Audio is also extracted from same source.

Comment: What kind of sync problem do you have? How do you combine audio and video? You have to be sure that explicit sample and frame rates are correct, and match the original, otherwise audio and video could be out of sync.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it, the pngs very dropping frames.